# Get text string from EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

It seems I can't figure out how to get the text string out of `EditText`.
I want to use the text from the `EditText` at pressing the button.

layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_menu_root"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/popup_menu_button"
        android:text="ok"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity :

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

  public String txtCheckin = "???";
  private String txtDescription = "???";
  private PopupWindow pw;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // get the instance of the LayoutInflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyClass.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // inflate our view from the corresponding XML file
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_root));
    // create a 100px width and 200px height popup window
    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 100, 200, true);

    final EditText edittextDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    // set actions to buttons we have in our popup
    Button button = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vv) {


        if (edittextDescription.getText() != null)
        {
            String newString = edittextDescription.getText().toString();
            transmitCheck("MANUAL", txtCheckin, "1", newString);
        }
        else
        {
            transmitCheck("MANUAL", txtCheckin, "1", "???");
        }


        finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 79):

```
EditText txtDescription =
        (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);


String message = txtDescription.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Can't you just do `String string = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription).getText().toString`?

Comment: Yes, you could. But doing that lookup twice is slower than keeping a reference to the EditText as well.

Comment: @Shark is it still slower now in 2018? Can you elaborate more why is it slower? I am a curious cat

Comment: it will always be slower. Android is not very clever when it comes to it's UI - which is why it generates the R.java file which contains a list of generated/hardcoded IDs to particular views so that you can "find" them on the screen via their parents.

That being said, if you find it once, and save a reference to that view, getting it's string text any number of times will be faster than finding it again (N number of times) and fetching it's string content.

You're free to measure how faster that is though.

Answer (score 17):

Try this :

```
EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String xyz = edt.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

Solved the problem myself:

```
final EditText edittextDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

must be

```
final EditText edittextDescription =  (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
```

And then I can do this to get the string

```
String s = edittext.getText().toString();
```