# Android conver String to int crashed app

Tags: android, string, int

When my app runs on S3, it crashes when it contains code to convert String from Textview to int. Here it is:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter_txt);
String txtNum = (String) tv.getText();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new Integer(txtNum), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The scenario is I put a number on screen, and it increase by one when user clicks. But when I convert the String number to int, it crashes. Someone knows it? Thank you.

Comment: use String txtNum = tv.getText().toString();

Comment: What is the log of the crash?

Comment: Can you pass integer to toast ?

Comment: before posting question see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324941/get-text-string-from-edittext

and this also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-on-android

Comment: I can pass integer to toast. I put my app on the phone, how can I see the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter_txt);
String txtNum  = tv.getText().toString();
Integer intNum = Integer.valueOf(txtNum); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txtNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it new Integer(txtNum).to string() . May be it will work I guess

Comment: That will convert integer back to String.