# Post data to Google Form from Android app

Tags: android

There are 2 textboxes, `ed1` and `ed2` in main activity and a save button.

```
final EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location_address);
final EditText ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.workername);

public void postData() {

    String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe5WZB-e95xrx3ZbwiOWtJx3wEuT-fJw/formResponse";
    HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();

    String data = "entry.748835646=" + URLEncoder.encode(location) + "&" + 
                  "entry.481985278=" + URLEncoder.encode(name);
    String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, data);
    Log.i(myTag, response);
}
```

I'm not getting what to write for the 2 edittexts above String data.

How to write code for `ed1` and `ed2`, such that after the user enters `ed1` and `ed1`, then clicking on save button, the data gets saved to Google Form? (that is the `postData` method gets executed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text string from EditText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324941/get-text-string-from-edittext)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void postData() {

String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe5WZB-e95xrx3ZbwiOWtJx3wEuT-fJw/formResponse";
HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();

String data = "entry.748835646=" + URLEncoder.encode(ed1.getText().toString()) + "&" + 
              "entry.481985278=" + URLEncoder.encode(ed2.getText().toString());
String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, data);
Log.i(myTag, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

The modified postData() method is as follows:-

public void postData() {

```
    String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe5WZbIwv6m5uqf2Z73Uh7B-e95xrx3ZbEuT-fJw/formResponse";
    HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();

    final EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location_address);
    final EditText ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.workername);

    location=ed1.getText().toString();
    name=ed2.getText().toString();


    String data = "entry.748835646=" + URLEncoder.encode(location) + "&" + 
                  "entry.481985278=" + URLEncoder.encode(name);
    String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, data);
    Log.i(myTag, response);
}
```